# EntityFramework Core auto generate key id property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations, entity-framework-core

Using .Net Core MVC.  I need to setup my model so that EntityFrameworkCore will auto generate the ID property.  I thought that just adding the `[Key]` annotation would do this, but it doesn't.  As a matter of fact, it produces an error when the ID field is left blank, which is always because I'm hiding it from the user.

I need it to instead Autogenerate a unique ID for the model every time.  How do I go about doing this? My ID property is currently of type `int`.

**ExampleModel**

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

**ExampleView**

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.ExampleModel

<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="ExampleModel">
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

**ExampleController**

```
public IActionResult Create ()
{
    return View();
}
public IActionResult Create (ExampleModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.ExampleModels.Add(model);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: you don't need [Key] attribute, is is primary key by default

Comment: But why doesn't it auto generate?

Comment: it should. Are you getting error when creating new item? Show code, how you do this.

Comment: you can add attribute: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]

Comment: @Alex I've tried using the attribute like you suggested, but still the same error.  The problem is that when the ID is left empty.  `ModelState.IsValid` returns false.

Comment: of course, you should pass model to the action with id

Comment: use tag helper: <input asp-for="SomeData" />

Comment: Wait, I'm confused.  I can't use asp-route to pass back the id because the model is not set to an instance of an object yet.  And I don't want an input for the ID to be available to the user.  I want it to auto generate an ID.

Comment: @JoeHigley - Why are you using `@Html.EditorForModel()` in your ExampleView? That will output the ID as an <input type="text"> form field, which will prevent ID field to be auto-generated.

Comment: @kimbaudi my ID property also has a `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` attribute

Comment: @JoeHigley, you should use `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` instead of `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` data annotation on your ID property. I post my solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to change your data annotations for your `ExampleModel` so that it auto generates a unique ID.

**ExampleModel**

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: lol. I figured this out right before you posted it.  But I will mark yours as the answer.  Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need DatabaseGenerated attribute. EF will set up identity for int PK by conventions.

Comment: @Smit - The reason for the DatabaseGenerated attribute is because **ExampleView** is using `@Html.EditorForModel()` to generate the form elements for the `ExampleModel`. If you copy the above code and omit the DatabaseGenerated attributes, you will get a text input for the ID property in your form and saving the form will NOT auto-generate an ID value, which is what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: thanks for this answer. using [Key] in conjunction with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] achieves the result i was expecting

Answer (score 1):

I guess another way to pass by ModelState validation is to remove it from ModelState.

```
ModelState.Remove("ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

To auto generate a key, you must define a DEFAULT constraint pointing to "NewId()". `[Key]` will only create a Primary Key constraint.

You can do this on the database itself or in the model generation

Comment: it isn't required in EF Core

Comment: @Alexan Hi but in EF Core after insert data into database I'm not getting newly auto generated `ID` back into model? after SaveChanges(); ? why any help?

Comment: @Neo if you are using GUIDs as ID, just use `Guid.CreateNew()` on your code and don't use either the constraint or the default... the guid generate on your code is guaranteed to be as unique as the one generated by the database

Comment: I'm using mysql and using Primary key auto generated , it is generated successfully and entry is added into database table as well ,  but after SaveChanges() when I see Id it is 0 .  int Id = myaddedObject.Id;

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  All I needed to do was add the Data Anotation `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]`  And now it works.